# "Могу ли я попросить вас(,) о рекомендации?"

Tags: пунктуация

Нужна ли запятая в предложении "Могу ли я попросить вас, о рекомендации?"

Comment: А вы-то как думаете?  Зачем там запятая, по какой мотивации? Почему именно там?

Answer (score 4):

Нет, не нужна. "О рекомендации" - дополнение, не требующее обособления.

Answer (score 0):

Вижу, что вопрос уже отвечен, повторю чуть более развёрнуто и с некоторыми дополнениями.

Никакого основания для простановки запятой нет. Просить о чём-либо и просить что-либо -- это единое словосочетание. Внутри него нет отдельных частей, которые нужно обособить.

Кстати, "просить рекомендации" (без "о") -- также вполне уместный оборот, сравни с "просить рекомендательное письмо".

И ещё, немного в шутку. Запятую уместно проставить здесь только в одном случае: если вы разговариваете с рекомендациями и обращаетесь к ним с какой-либо просьбой. 
Вполне возможно представить какой-либо фантастический рассказ, либо детскую книжку где подобная ситуация была бы уместна. 
Откроем, например, "Приключения Алисы в стране чудес" в переводе Н. Демуровой:

> — Заговорить с ней или  нет?  -  подумала  Алиса.  -  Сегодня  все 
>   так удивительно,  что,  возможно,  и  она  умеет  говорить!  Во 
>   всяком  случае, попытаться стоит!
>
> И она начала:
>
> — О Мышь! Не знаете ли вы, как выбраться из этой лужи? Мне так 
>   надоело здесь плавать, о Мышь!
>
> Алиса считала, что именно так и следует обращаться к мышам. Опыта у
>   нее никакого  не  было,  но  она   вспомнила   учебник   латинской грамматики, принадлежащий ее брату.
>
> "Именительный - Мышь,
>
> Родительный - Мыши,
>
> Дательный - Мыши,
>
> Винительный - Мышь,
>
> Звательный - О Мышь!"

Впрочем, поскольку я предполагаю, что у вас совершенно не этот случай, а использование в обычной речи, повторю ещё раз -- запятая не нужна.

Comment: *Вижу, что вопрос уже отвечен, повторю чуть более развёрнуто* - и напрасно это делаете. Нет никакого смысла выполнять тут работу корректора.

Comment: Задумался над тем, насколько уместно тогда было заменить вопросительный знак (просьба, вопрос) на восклицательный (обращение).